# Proving $a^4+2a^3 b+2ab^3+b^4 ≥ 6a^2b^2$

Tags: inequality

Prove that for any positive real numbers $a$ and $b$,$$a^4 + 2a^3b + 2ab^3 + b^4 ≥ 6a^2b^2.$$I tried using Vieta's formula to show the product of the LHS is greater than the RHS, but I don't think I am correct.

Comment: What does this have to do with Vieta's formula?

Comment: Have you tried AM-GM inequality? If yes, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have not tried the AM-GM inequality.  I did think of that, but wasn't exactly sure how to start.  Thanks for all the answers I see.  This helps a lot.

Comment: Direct AM-GM?  $ $

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the inequality and employ AM-GM:

$$a^4+a^3b+a^3b+ab^3+ab^3+b^4 \ge 6\sqrt[6]{a^{12}b^{12}} =6a^2b^2$$

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM inequality we have $$a^4+b^4\geq 2a^2b^2$$ and $$a^3b+ab^3\geq 2a^2b^2 $$
Adding both the quations after multiplying the second one by $2$ we get the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily prove it using AM-GM Inequality or Lagrange method. Using AM-GM Inequality,

$$ \frac {a^4 + b^4}{2} \ge a^2.b^2 $$
$$ \frac {a^2 + b^2}{2} \ge a.b$$

$$ \text {Also, you can write }a^3.b+a.b^3 = ab.(a^2+b^2)$$

$$ \text {So, } a^4 + b^4 +2a^3.b+2a.b^3 \ge 6.a^2.b^2$$